# Scraping breadcrumb links recursively with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, breadcrumbs

I am a newbie in python and scrapy. For a university project, I need to scrape car classifieds on the autoscout24.de domain (in german).

Here is an example site: http://ww3.autoscout24.de/classified/268487991?asrc=fa|as&testvariant=articles_t20&tierlayer=fa

I want the CrawlSpider to scrape the 'next offer' ('nächstes Angebot') recursively, but could not seem to extract the link from the breadcrumb. The interesting part of the site should be:

```
<div class="floatRight">
                    <span class="linkInvisible">
                        <span class="floatLeft">‹</span>
                        <span class="floatLeft marginLeftXS">
                            vorheriges Angebot
                        </span>
                    </span>


                <p class="floatLeft marginLeftXS">|</p>   


                    <a id="breadCrumbNextOffer" ng-click="breadCrumb.nextOffer('http://ww3.autoscout24.de/classified/266709231')">
                        <span class="floatLeft marginLeftXS">
                            nächstes Angebot
                        </span>
                        <p class="floatLeft marginLeftXS">›</p>
                    </a>

            </div>
```

I would like to get the link inside breadCrumb.nextOffer(...)

I have tried this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from autocrawler.items import AutocrawlerItem


class AutocrawlerRecursiveSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'autocrawler_recursive'
    allowed_domains = ['autoscout24.de']
    start_urls = ['http://ww3.autoscout24.de/classified/268348256asrc=pl|as&testvariant=articles_t20&tierlayer=pl']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/^http:\/\/ww3.autoscout24.de\/classified\/\w+$/'), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="ng-app"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div')),  callback='parse_item', follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    item = AutocrawlerItem()
    item['brand'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="detailsContent"]/div[1]/h1/text()').extract()
    item['price'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="detailsContent"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/text()').extract()
    return item
```

But this would only scrape the start_url and can't seem to find the next links.

I would be very thankful of any input. :)

Comment: a similar problem has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556962/how-can-i-use-scrapy-to-parse-links-in-js basically you update the Rule extractor to get out the value of attribute ng-click and process the value to extract the uerl within another function.

Comment: thanks. it led me to realize that the problem is that scrapy does not support javascript generated content.